# Auto Layout vertical space calculation method

Tags: ios, autolayout

I'm studying [Auto Layout Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/AnatomyofaConstraint.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH9-SW1) and however it's straightforward how Horizontal Constraints work, I can't understand how it calculated vertical spacing on Y axes in this example (which is pseudocode):

[image]

```
Vertical Constraints:
Red.top = 1.0 * Superview.top + 20.0
...


Horizontal Constraints:
Red.leading = 1.0 * Superview.leading + 20.0
...
```

If we imaging Superview.top is located at (x: , y: 100) then according to the first constraint, Red.top will be located at: 1 * 100 + 20 which means (x: , y: 120) which is upper than Superview.top! so why is it located below the Superview.top in the image above!?

Comment: With the same logic, why the `Red.leading` is not ahead of `superView.leading`.

Comment: My point was finally the view is saying that it is not 120 upper to its superView. It is ideally saying the subview's y is at a position 120 from the superview's top.

Comment: If you imagine these two attributes on X axis, Red.leading is ahead of superView.leading.

Comment: I found the answer at the end of Auto Layout Guide :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you got this doubt because of lack of knowledge in iOS coordinate system,

In iOS, there are two main types of coordinate systems:

**An upper-left-origin coordinate system (ULO)**, in which the origin of drawing operations is at the upper-left corner of the drawing area, with positive values extending downward and to the right. The default coordinate system used by the UIKit and Core Animation frameworks is ULO-based.

**A lower-left-origin coordinate system (LLO)**, in which the origin of drawing operations is at the lower-left corner of the drawing area, with positive values extending upward and to the right. The default coordinate system used by Core Graphics framework is LLO-based.

Please take a look on below image,*Default coordinate systems in iOS*
[image: *Default coordinate systems in iOS*]

So as per **ULO** we measure the y axis from the top.

Referal:
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/GraphicsDrawingOverview/GraphicsDrawingOverview.html

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/Devpedia-CocoaApp/CoordinateSystem.html

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Auto Layout Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/AnatomyofaConstraint.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH9-SW1), for Top, Bottom and Baseline attributes, the values increase as you move down the screen. So it works against normal Y axis values.